# The Orange Triangle Badges Symbol Doesn't Feel Right

Tags: discussion

The orange triangle that symbolizes badges on Graphic Design

[image: screenshot]

reminds me of "caution" symbols that I see while driving.

For example, the [road construction sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_site_safety#Hazards_to_non-workers):

[image: road construction sign]

Or the [slow-moving vehicle sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-speed_vehicle):

[image: slow moving vehicle symbol]

Maybe it's just me, but when I see this, my instinct is to feel cautious. It feels as though there are 4 errors with my account that I must fix.

Again, maybe it's just me, but perhaps it's not and this might be better changed. Perhaps using a different color like blue or green.

Comment: I think there's a slim chance it will be changed to blue or green, it's supposed to represent bronze

Answer (score 6):

As John says, the colour will not be changed.

It might make more sense if you see it in connection with the silver and gold badges as well:

[image]

And, from the designer, the idea behind these geometric shapes are simply because they are taken from the logo of this site:

[image]